# Accessible Error-Handling with WAI-ARIA - Best Practive?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'd like to inform users of assistive technologies (like braille or screenreader) about invalid input-fields, using [WAI-ARIA-Attributes](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria).

I've tried two approaches which work both, but I don't know which one is best practice. Please share your thoughts on this.

**Approach 1**

Using aria-describedby. SR and Braille read the label, unless an error-message exists.
Possible drawback: It appears some older SRs have issues with wai-aria-attributes. Also even more global ids.

```
<input
 id="{{unique-id}}"
 type="text"
 aria-describedby="{{unique-id}}-error-message"
>

<label
 for="{{unique-id}}"
>
 {{title}}
</label>

<p
 id="{{unique-id}}-error-message"
 role="alert"
>
 {{error-message}}
</p>
```

**Approach 2**

Using title and aria-label. Title for backwards-compatibility.
Possible drawback: Redundant text that has to be send from server to client.

```
<input
 id="{{unique-id}}"
 type="text"
 title="{{title}} {{error-message}}"
 aria-label="{{title}} {{error-message}}"
>

<label
 for="{{unique-id}}"
>
 {{title}}
</label>

<p>
 {{error-message}}
</p>
```

A combination of both approaches prioritizes attributes in following order (if supported):

- aria-label
- title
- aria-describedby

Any thoughts on best practice on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at the ARIA states added explicitly for the purpose of form validation:

- [aria-required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-required_attribute) (and/or HTML5's [required](http://john.foliot.ca/required-inputs/) attribute)
- [aria-invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-invalid_attribute)

This [code is from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-invalid_attribute) - visit the site for more information.

```
<input name="email" id="email" aria-required="true" reqiured 
  aria-invalid="false" onblur="checkValidity('email', '@', 'Invalid e-mail address');"/>

<script>
  function checkValidity(aID, aSearchTerm, aMsg) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(aID);
    var invalid = (elem.value.indexOf(aSearchTerm) < 0);
    if (invalid) {
      elem.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "true");
      updateAlert(aMsg); // show your ARIA alert message
    } else {
      elem.setAttribute("aria-invalid", "false");
      updateAlert();     // remove your ARIA alert message
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: True, those should also be set. Thank you very much, TimmyHayes!

Answer (score 0):

**Third option : using Native Client Side Validation with  Constraint Validation API**

This requires Javascript but you will be sure the browser will implement natively the error message and give that information to the Accessibility API.

```
document.getElementById("{{unique-id}}").setCustomValidity("21 characters expected");
```

I would not use this solution without using sufficient visual information which would not require the user to submit the form before viewing the error message. If your approach can answer to that, I also like the [G139: Creating a mechanism that allows users to jump to errors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/G139) technique

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will also evaluate that approach. Good reverence! :)